# ERROR: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle

After installing Oracle and opening Command Prompt, I typed in 
sqlplus "/as sysdba" 
and got an error message 
ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
and then it asks me to enter the user-name.
I'm using my own personal computer and although the name given after C:\Users\ is not called "Administrator", it's my username when I used to log in to this computer and since I'm the only one using the computer I'm assuming it's the same as "Administrator" and when I opened account settings it says administrator under my account name.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.228]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\linus>sqlplus "/as sysdba"

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Aug 20 10:56:53 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


Enter user-name:
```

What might be the cause of this and what can I do to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> since I'm the only one using the computer I'm assuming it's the same as "Administrator"

That's not enough to be an Administrator.

Make sure that your user belongs to `ORA_DBA` OR `ORA_<%ORACLE_SID%>_DBA` OS group on Windows.

As well check the value set for `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES` parameter on `sqlnet.ora`(`%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin`) file. `NTS` should be included in the value.

`SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)`